# Need nosql database for queries with bitwise condition

Tags: sql, cassandra, bit-manipulation, nosql

I am currently using apache cassandra database for storing information.
But cassandra does not allow to perform queries with bitwise operations.

I need to execute query:

select count(*) from table where field1 = ? and BIT_COUNT(field2 ^ ?) <= 10;

But cassandra does not allow it.

Can you advice some nosql or embedded fast sql solution?

Database contains greater than 1 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with Cassandra otherwise, you could add Spark and use Spark SQL to do queries like that. Spark has an open-source connector to use Cassandra as its distributed database.

There's also DataStax Enterprise which would allow you to integrate with Hadoop/Hive and get similar analytic capabilities. (DataStax Enterprise is also an easy way to get Spark functionality.)

Comment: What is this apache spark? Also database which own cluster or what?

Comment: Yes, Apache Spark is capable of replacing Hadoop's M/R framework and is more flexible, faster and has less overhead than hadoop's M/R. It requires an underlying distributed database like Cassandra (or Hadoop's HDFS).

I'm not sure what your database/cluster question is asking about, can you elaborate?.

Comment: Question in that how spark process the data, it load data in memory or how?

Comment: And. Whether spark has own data storage or only use underlying Cassandra?

Comment: Spark loads the data into memory and has a disk spill-over mechanism if that's not sufficient. Spark does not have it's own data storage mechanism as far as I know, but relies on "resilient distributed datasets" (RDDs) that the author provides. Each RDD could potentially rely on a different underlying technology (cassandra, hdfs, etc).  It only writes back to Cassandra what you specifically tell it to write back.